# Prove that $\lim_{n\to ∞}\frac{\alpha(n)}{n}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that $$\lim_{n\to ∞}\frac{\alpha(n)}{n}=0$$ Where $\alpha(n)$ is the number of primes that divide n.

Tip: the fact that every prime number is ≥ 2 provides a simple estimation of how small it should be $\alpha(n)$.

any suggestions for how to tackle the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $\alpha(n) = k$, where the corresponding primes are $p_1, \ldots, p_k$, then $n \ge p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_k \ge 2^k$.